# Google Wallet Digital Goods JS Security Error

Tags: javascript, android-pay

I'm attempting to integrate Google Wallet for Digital Goods into a WordPress plugin and while following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial I'm receiving the error below in Chrome:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://sandbox.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I've simplified down an example HTML file that reproduces the issue for me (included below) that is basically just an HTML doc that loads the buy.js file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

I've also tried loading the JS file from within the local domain to no avail.  I also noticed that I get the same error on the Google Wallet sample page at https://iap-php.appspot.com/.

Any idea what I can do to get around this? I'm sure it's simple but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce (I don't use Wordpress, so this is confined to the sample link, and local http/s dev)....

Comment: Update to anyone that looks at this later... I was unable to get rid of the error I described above but after some further work, it doesn't seem to be preventing Google Wallet from completing a transaction.  I had other issues in my code that was preventing that.  Once fixed, everything appears to be working fine.